# Most probable sum of $2$ dice

Tags: probability

A die has 20 identical equilateral triangular faces numbered from 1 to 20. If
two such dice are rolled the most probable sum of the numbers showing on the
top faces is $x$. Determine $x$

How do I do this? I'm not sure how to start. Any hints?

Comment: Try checking how many ways the first few sums can be obtained, and see if you can generalize.

Answer (score 1):

If it were a typical cubical die, numbered $1$ through $6$, the possible combinations would be
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}$$
What's the most probable sum in this case? Do you see what the answer is for your die now?

Comment: $7$. It means the most probable sum for my die is $21$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: But what is the way to do it algebraically?

Comment: @ZevChonoles can we just use the fact that mean value of a dice throw is 3.5 i.e $\mu=3.5=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6i$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: do this question with $6$-sided dice. Then you can just brute force all results. (If you still have problem, do $4$-sided dice) Observe the pattern and think about why this happens.

Comment: I just wrote down all the sums and found that the post probable sum for a $6$ sided die is $7$. What would be the algebraic approach?

Comment: What combinations yields $7$? Did you find out why $7$ is the answer for $6$-sided case? Same thing happens for $20$-sided ones. A die can have all possible outcome in equal probability, so you want the most of them.

Comment: No I couldn't find out.

Comment: The reason is that as the table of Zev Chonoles shows, $7$ can be yielded with all faces involved, from $1$ to $6$. Other numbers cannot be obtained with certain number on one face. For example, $5$, when a die rolls $5$ or $6$, you can't get $5$. Or $8$, when a die rolls $1$, you can't get $8$. Same thing occurs for $20$ sides.